# Convert DFS to Binary Tree

Tags: binary-tree, traversal, depth-first-search

Can I form a binary tree from a given dfs traversal?
I mean, say that I have inorder, preorder, postorder, or all of the three, can I have one unique binary tree from these traverse whit no ambiguity with another tree?

Answer (score 0):

You could restore any binary tree given its preorder traversal of all their nodes, including the external ones. In order to do that, you must distinguish the internal nodes from the external ones. The external nodes are the empty trees, which are equivalent to `NULL` pointers in many implementations.

For example,for the following binary tree

[image]

The internal nodes are labeled with `a` and the external with `b`.

So the preorder traversal is

```
aaaabbabbaabbbababb
```

It could be shown that the language of all possible preorder codes is injective, so, you could invert the preorder sequence and to restore the original tree.

Some such as (psudocode):

```
Node * preorder_to_tree(char *& ptr)
{
  if (*ptr++ == ''b')
    return nullptr;

  Node * p = new Node;
  LLINK(p) = preorder_to_tree(ptr);
  RLINK(p) = preorder_to_tree(ptr);

  return p;
}
```

Of course, the algorithm assumes a valid preorder sequence.

If you store keys in the internal nodes, then you could use a special key for denoting the empty tree and the algorithm would be the same.

Comment: What if we didn't know how many child each node has? I mean, preorder traversal of (a, b, c, d, e) can be written (b, a, d, c, e), (c, b, a, d, e), etc. in inorder traversal. How can we know which one is the desired tree? I don't think preorder alone is enough to create the tree :/

Comment: I'm assuming, as you have indicated. that we are dealing with binary trees. So, each internal node always has two subtrees, with three possible combinations: full node with both subtrees different of empty tree, an incomplete node with an empty subtree and a leaf node with both subtrees empty. Now if you deal with a m-tree, then you can eventually get an equivalent binary tree whose preorder traversal is equal to the preorder traversal on the m-tree. I suggest to review Knuth TAOCP V I in order to get a better comprehension of this equivalence

Comment: I don't think so. Binary tree can be empty (?). by the way, what does it means full node and incomplete node?

Comment: Well Ronald, study the matter a little more and then gladly I can help you. Good luck!

Comment: okay, I will. Which part of TAOCP I should I read so that I can immediately get a clear understanding for this matter?

Comment: 2.3.1 & 2.3.2, V 1, 3rd ed